# Can't get form value with PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I am trying to get the value of a form (text field) with _POST, and store it to a text file but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="">
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='example.com/index.php?address=true';" value="ODOSLAŤ" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['address'])) {

    $email = $_POST['test'];

    $myfile = fopen("log.txt","a") or die("Error.");
    fwrite($myfile, "\n".$email);

    // this prints nothing
    echo $email;  
  }
```

I can't get the value of that text field. Nor GET nor POST doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you wanna get address which you havent declared anywhere, second of all you have to declare a method in your form like <form action="/action_page.php" method="post"> or <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">

Comment: I would recommend you to just go through basic of PHP and HTML.

Comment: I do have "address" declared, when you click the Submit button it declares "address" as TRUE and the function runs well. If I add ann echo at the end, it prints - but $email variable is still empty. I tried declaring form action and method but no difference.

Comment: @KristiánFilo if you would mind making my answer the correct answer since I was the first one to come up with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are missing a post method in your form.

```
<form method="post" action="example.com/index.php?address=true">
     <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="">
     <input type="submit" value="ODOSLAŤ" />
</form>
```

### You also have to change the following line.

```
if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
```

### With

```
if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
```

*You want to post after triggering an action as FreedomPride mentioned*

### Conclusion

You want to declare for example a `post method`if you know that you would like to post that data in the future.

As FreedomPride also mentioned :

You are using a `GET`, but if a user does not input anything your script won't work, there by it is recommended to use a `POST`

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting your form.

Change your code as follows....

```
<form method="post" action="example.com/index.php?address=true">
     <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="">
     <input type="submit" value="ODOSLAŤ" />
</form>
```

You'll get what you want....

Answer (score -1):

This is what you're missing as Tomm mentioned.

```
<form method="post" action="yourphp.php">
<input type="text" name="address" id="test" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

In your PHP, it should be post if it was triggered

```
if (isset($_POST['address'])) {

    $email = $_POST['test'];

    $myfile = fopen("log.txt","a") or die("Error.");
    fwrite($myfile, "\n".$email);

    // this prints nothing
    echo $email;  
  }
```

Explanation :-

In a form, an action is required to pass the action to the next caller with action. The action could be empty or pass it's value to another script.

In your PHP you're actually using a `GET`. What if the user didn't input anything. That's why it's recommended to use `POST` .